# Difference between two struct initializations

Tags: c, struct, initialization, compound-literals

What is the difference between the following two initializations for a `Struct`?

```
Car ford = {
    .name = "Ford F-150",
    .price = 25000
};
```

And:

```
Car dodge = (Car) {
    .name = "Ram",
    .price = 1000
};
```

---

From [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/8K9roc), it looks like the two produce the same code:

[image]

---

What does the `(StructName)` do when preceding the struct? It seems its necessary when doing complex initializations such as:

```
CarPtr mazda = & (Car) {
    .name = "Mazda",
    .price = 20000
};
```

Also related, to the two answers from [Possible to initialize/assign a struct pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65603903/possible-to-initialize-assign-a-struct-pointer/65604058#65604058).

Comment: See this Q/A about [compound literals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/330793/10871073). Perhaps not the best post, but there are many others on compound literals in C.

Comment: It's not necessary when initializing a struct variable. You need it when initializing a pointer, because the pointer needs an object to point to, and the compound literal creates an object.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal

Comment: @Barmar wouldn't the object be `{...}` ? Why would the `(ObjType)` be needed to specify that?

Comment: You can't create an object with just `{...}`. That's an initializer list, so it can only be used when initializing a struct. Compound literals were invented to allow anonymous objects to be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this declaration

```
Car dodge = (Car) {
    .name = "Ram",
    .price = 1000
};
```

there are created two objects of the type Car. The first one is the unnamed compound literal

```
(Car) {
    .name = "Ram",
    .price = 1000
}
```

that is used to initialize another named object dodge.

From C Standard (6.5.2.5 Compound literals)

> 3 A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized type name
> followed by a braceenclosed list of initializers is a compound
> literal. It provides an unnamed object whose value is given by the
> initializer list.

In fact it is similar to the following declarations

```
Car ford = {
    .name = "Ford F-150",
    .price = 25000
};

Car dodge = ford;
```

The difference is that in the last example we created one more named object.

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 13 The initializer for a structure or union object that has automatic
> storage duration shall be either an initializer list as described
> below, or a single expression that has compatible structure or union
> type. In the latter case, the initial value of the object, including
> unnamed members, is that of the expression.

Comment: would both initializations take up the same amount of memory in storage, or does creating the second object double it or?

Comment: @David542 The compound literal will be alive in the scope where it is defined. That is as I wrote you created two objects.